# Finding top values in each cell using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cell-statistics

I have 60 raster files and I need to find the top 5 values in each cell.

Now I know that if I had to find the highest value, I could just use the maximum function in cell statistics. But I am not able to find the top 5 in each cell nor can I find a solution through which I can identify the top 5.

Is there any toolbox or any other method that I could use?

Comment: Read all 60 bands to an arcpy array then iterate the values to find the highest 5 or 10 or 20. Do you need to be able to find which raster each of the top values comes from?

Comment: @MichaelStimson yes, I need to be able to find which raster the top 5 come from. Also, I have never used python. Would there be any tutorial where I can learn how to do this in arcpy?

Comment: This is a little too advanced for a beginner, have a read of arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000 then for each index (cell) make a dictionary from the band data and sort like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value then grab the first 5 keys and their values. The ArcGIS help has many examples of basic code to get you started; if you're an absolute beginner then google 'learn python' before getting into arcpy to get some basis on the language.

Comment: The real question how do you want your result?

Comment: @FelixIP I want to find the top 5 crop raster values in each cell. I have a separate list of 7 crops. If any of the top 5 rasters belong to my list of 7 crops, I will assign it a value (depending upon which crop it is)

Comment: Perhaps run 7 times rank tool on your set of rasters http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/rank.htm

Comment: And use Combine afterwards.